# Play mp3 files with AVAudioPlayer with PlayAndRecord category?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, simultaneous

Hi I have a setup that records audio (with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category), now I want to playback and MP3 file as usual with AVAudioPlayer instance, but no any sound can be hear.

AVAudioPlayer do not throw any error, nor in its delegate callbacks.

Has anybody similar experience? How to overcome this?

Comment: I can work around with OpelAL playback, but if there was a bit more high level solution, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Please check your volume :)

Comment: Seems it has not too much to do with the recording session... something else...

Answer (score 0):

Please use this -

```
 NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", docDirPath , @"Welcome"];
     NSError *error;
            NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
            avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];

            if (avPlayer == nil) 
            {
                NSLog(@"AudioPlayer did not load properly: %@", [error description]);
            }
            else
              {
                [avPlayer play];
           avPlayer.delegate=self;
               }
```

And tell me if it is working or not.